# handle detail page for table view controller in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a table view controller with cells. on clicking a cell I load another view controller and I want to handle elements on this view controller. on the detail view controller I placed a label and in the first step I want to set the text of the label, but I get an exception `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and I don't know why. Are there any solutions?

This is the part of my table view controller on clicking a cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let vcMissionDetail : ViewControllerMissionDetail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MissionDetail") as ViewControllerMissionDetail;

    //load detail view controller
    self.presentViewController(vcMissionDetail, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //set label text
    //at this line I get the exception -> label is nil
    vcMissionDetail.label.text = "Test"
}
```

And this is my detail view controller (very simple):

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerMissionDetail: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

THX!

Comment: What line of code does the error point to?

Comment: You are getting that error because label is nil. Did you forget to connect the label to a UILabel in your storyboard?

Comment: On the line `vcMissionDetail.label.text = "Test"` I get the exception. And I also referenced the label in detail view controller in storyboard with the `label` variable (see `@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns an optional because it may fail due to several reasons. So you should better unwrap it conditionally:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let vcMissionDetail : ViewControllerMissionDetail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MissionDetail") as ViewControllerMissionDetail {

        //set label text before presenting the viewController
        vcMissionDetail.label.text = "Test"

        //load detail view controller
        self.presentViewController(vcMissionDetail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Further things to double check:

Is `ViewControllerMissionDetail` set as the custom class for your viewController in the identity inspector in InterfaceBuilder?

If the `vcMissionDetail` is successfully instantiated and it still crashes then delete the label's outlet connection in InterfaceBuilder and recreate it.

Comment: I did the things you've mentioned but without success. Yesterday I think the code works, but I'm not sure. Is it possible that it is a bug in xcode?

Comment: I bet your IBOutlet connect to the label is invalid. Did you try to delete and recreate the connection?

Comment: Yes, I did it. And also I added a new label to check it, but with the same problem. One thing I recognized...after creating the second IBOutlet for the second label in detail view controller, there was no autocompletion entry for this label as I called it in table view controller. Maybe it is a problem of Xcode? I reinstalled Xcode but without success.

Comment: Your custom class is probably not set in the identity inspector.

Comment: The custom class is set to `ViewControllerMissionDetail`. That's not the problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is pretty straight forward. If I'm understanding correctly, you want to change the label on your detail view controller when you segue from table view controller using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. 
The place where you are probably making a mistake is, you're trying to change the label in your detail view controller from the table view controller.
The correct approach to your problem would be to set the label text in the 'viewDidLoad' or 'viewDidAppear' method of the detail view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //set label text here
}
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //OR set label text here
}
```

Comment: But it has to be possible because later I want to set the label text with an information of the table view cell. This information I only have in the table view controller or? And I instatiate the detail view controller in table view controller.

Comment: I can understand. I was in a similar situation. This is the approach I used (it might not be the best way to go about your issue but it worked for me). In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of table view controller store the cell data of the selected row in a global variable. Now you can use this global variable in your detail view controller to set label text.

Answer (score 0):

For swift:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showItemDetail", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showItemDetail" {
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let detailVC:ItemDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ItemDetailViewController
        detailVC.item = items[indexPath.row] as Item

    }
}
```